# How to get URL of different webpack entry?

Tags: webpack

My webpack config has multiple entries:

```
entry: {
  main: './index.tsx',
  sharingServiceWorker: '../sw/sharingServiceWorker.ts',
},
```

How can I get URL of `sharingServiceWorker` in `index.tsx`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution - [entry-loader](https://github.com/eoin/entry-loader).